# conda create shows TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_retries'

Tags: python, conda

I'm using windows 7, python 2.7.10, conda 3.14.1.  When I create a simple conda environment using `conda create -n webhook conda` 
It shows `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_retries'`
The entire traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 4, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 201, in m
ain
    args_func(args, p)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 208, in a
rgs_func
    args.func(args, p)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\common.py", line 612, in
 inner
    return func(args, parser)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 50
, in execute
    install.install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 255, i
n install
    offline=args.offline)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\common.py", line 549, in
 get_index_trap
    return get_index(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\api.py", line 42, in get_ind
ex
    unknown=unknown)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\utils.py", line 119, in __ca
ll__
    value = self.func(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 228, in fetc
h_index
    session = CondaSession()
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\connection.py", line 67, in
__init__
    http_adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_retries'
```

Comment: Conda `3.14` is rather old.  Just run `conda update conda`.